# How to make tensorflow median filter?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to build GAN structure on my own

at tensorflow homepage doesn't exist about median filter function

and i hope to add median filter function after generated image more cleaner

how can i do that??

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a median filter using `tf.image.extract_patches` to simulate a sliding window and `tf.math.top_k` to get the median:

```
def median_filter(data, filt_length=3):
    '''
    Computes a median filtered output of each [n_bins, n_channels] data sample
        and returns output w/ same shape, but median filtered

    NOTE: as TF doesnt have a median filter implemented, this had to be done in very hacky way...
    '''
    edges = filt_length// 2

    # convert to 4D, where data is in 3rd dim (e.g. data[0,0,:,0]
    exp_data = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(data, 0), -1)
    # get rolling window
    wins = tf.image.extract_patches(images=exp_data, sizes=[1, filt_length, 1, 1],
                       strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
    # get median of each window
    wins = tf.math.top_k(wins, k=2)[0][0, :, :, edges]
    # Concat edges
    out = tf.concat((data[:edges, :], wins, data[-edges:, :]), 0)

    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this pull request.

I have added this method in tensorflow addons.

https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/pull/111

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `tfa.image.median_filter2d`.

Here you have the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/median_filter2d).